# raise MissingSchema( MissingSchema: Invalid URL in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qs


folder = 'images_test'
os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)

root_folder = os.getcwd()

baseurl = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/category/3710/home-decor.html?spm=a2g0o.home.107.9.650c2145X9NKoP/'

# an array for all the product links
product_links = [] 

# going through all the pages of the shop
for x in range(1, 7):
    url = f'https://www.aliexpress.com/category/3710/home-decor.html?spm=a2g0o.home.107.9.650c2145X9NKoP/page/{x}'
    print(url)
    
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    product_list = soup.find_all('div', class_= "content--container--2dDeH1y")
    # taking all the links to each product page
    for item in product_list:
        for link in item.find_all('a', href=True, class_="manhattan--container--1lP57Ag cards--gallery--2o6yJVt"):
            product_links.append(link['href'])
            # appending the links previously taken to the array

product_items_list = []

i = 0
d = {}  # use as set() 

os.chdir(folder)

for link_test in product_links:
    

    r = requests.get(link_test)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
    
    title = soup.find('h1', class_='product_title').text.strip()
    price = soup.find('p', class_ = 'price').text.strip()
    header = soup.find('div', class_ = 'woocommerce-product-details__short-description').text.strip()
    sku  = soup.find('span', class_ = 'sku').text.strip()
    categories = soup.find('span' , class_ = 'posted_in').text.strip()
    description = soup.find('div', class_ = 'wc-tab-inner').text.strip()
    brand = soup.find('div', id = 'tab-pwb_tab-content').text.strip()

    images = soup.select('img', class_ = "manhattan--img--36QXbtQ product-img")
    
    # --- before `for`-loop ---
    
    downloaded = []
    
    # --- `for`-loop ---
    
    for image in images:
        link = image['src']
        if link in d:
            name = d[link]
            downloaded.append(name)
        else:
            i += 1
            name = str(i) +'img.jpg'
            d[link] = name
            print('link:', link)
            print('name:', name)
            print('---')
            # here i am adding the .jpg and saving the images
            with open(name, 'wb') as f:
                im = requests.get(link)
                #print("URMEAZA DEBUG: {}".format(im))
                f.write(im.content)
            downloaded.append(name)
            
    # --- after `for`-loop ---
    
    # storing all the infos about this product 
    product = {
        'sku': sku,
        'categories': categories,
        'name' : title,
        'description': description,
        'short_description': header,
        'price' : price[0:5],
        'images': downloaded,
    }
    product_items_list.append(product)


os.chdir(root_folder)

df = pd.DataFrame(product_items_list)
print(df)
df.to_csv('aziz3.csv')
```

that problem :

```
  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File c:\users\aziz3\desktop\new folder (2)\paloma.py:43
    r = requests.get(link_test)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py:73 in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py:59 in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:573 in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:484 in prepare_request
    p.prepare(

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:368 in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)

  File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:439 in prepare_url
    raise MissingSchema(

MissingSchema: Invalid URL '//www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004696733559.html?algo_pvid=0f8ad776-26e1-4ff3-b0db-d1a0d421fd03&algo_exp_id=0f8ad776-26e1-4ff3-b0db-d1a0d421fd03-0&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21MAD%2191.8%213.94%21%21%21%21%21%40211bf31716825292368193713d07e4%2112000030134332941%21sea%21MA%210&curPageLogUid=kBu6G370fwtQ': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http:////www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004696733559.html?algo_pvid=0f8ad776-26e1-4ff3-b0db-d1a0d421fd03&algo_exp_id=0f8ad776-26e1-4ff3-b0db-d1a0d421fd03-0&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21MAD%2191.8%213.94%21%21%21%21%21%40211bf31716825292368193713d07e4%2112000030134332941%21sea%21MA%210&curPageLogUid=kBu6G370fwtQ?


MissingSchema: Invalid URL '//www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004696733559.html?algo_pvid=0f8ad776-26e1-4ff3-b0db-d1a0d421fd03&algo_exp_id=0f8ad776-26e1-4ff3-b0db-d1a0d421fd03-0&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21MAD%2191.8%213.94%21%21%21%21%21%40211bf31716825292368193713d07e4%2112000030134332941%21sea%21MA%210&curPageLogUid=kBu6G370fwtQ': No scheme supplied. Perhaps you meant http:////www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004696733559.html?algo_pvid=0f8ad776-26e1-4ff3-b0db-d1a0d421fd03&algo_exp_id=0f8ad776-26e1-4ff3-b0db-d1a0d421fd03-0&pdp_npi=3%40dis%21MAD%2191.8%213.94%21%21%21%21%21%40211bf31716825292368193713d07e4%2112000030134332941%21sea%21MA%210&curPageLogUid=kBu6G370fwtQ?
```

Comment: Looks like your links are missing the protocol part (https).

Comment: please how to fix that ?